# Update XML Insert Node before specific node using PHP

Tags: xml, domdocument, php

I have an XML displaying client logos and want to add logo through PHP panel. Current XML code is :

```
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_5.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_6.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_7.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_8.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_9.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_10.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_11.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_12.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_13.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_14.gif]]></image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <image><![CDATA[images/clients_15.gif]]></image>
    </item>

    <footer><![CDATA[copyright evolve entertainment and marketing solutions, 2009]]></footer>

</clients>
```

PHP code is :

```
if(!empty($_FILES["logo"]["name"]))
{
    $handle = new Upload($_FILES["logo"]);  
    $imgId = uniqid();      
    if ($handle->uploaded) 
    {
        $handle->file_name_body_pre =   $imgId;
        $handle->image_resize            = false;
        $handle->Process(ROOT_PATH.'images/');
        $handle->processed;
    }
    $imgName = $imgId.$_FILES["logo"]['name'];

    $parent_path = "//main";
    $next_path = "//main/clients/footer"; 
    $xpath = new DomXPath($doc); 
    $parent = $xpath->query($parent_path); 
    $next = $xpath->query($next_path);



    $imageNode = $doc->createElement('image');
    $cdata=$doc->createCDATASection($imgName);
    $imageNode = $imageNode->appendChild($cdata);

    //$parent->item(0)->insertBefore($imageNode, $next->item(0)); 

    $section = $doc->insertBefore($imageNode,$next->item(0));

    $doc->save(XML_PATH.'clients.xml');
```

Where I want to add new node either before footer or at Top in  child node. When I tried above code it serve an error as : Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

Comment: How are you defining `$doc`?

Comment: $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load(XML_PATH.'clients.xml');

Comment: What line is throwing this error? What PHP code do you have on this line number?

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Not Found Error'

This means that a node is not found. You didn't specify the line but I assume it is:

```
$section = $doc->insertBefore($imageNode, $next->item(0));
```

And this is problematic. `$doc` is the root element, however it is not the parent element of `$next->item(0)`. To have this to work, the *refnode* (here: `$next->item(0)`) needs to be a child of `$doc` - but it is not.

Instead here is a simple but extensive example which also gives some better speaking code:

```
$refnode = $next->item(0);
$parent  = $refnode->parentNode;
$section = $parent->insertBefore($imageNode, $refnode);
```

Sure you don't need to use that many variables, but the example should lead you the way, especially see `$refnode->parentNode` to get the correct node from which to insert before any of it's children.

And yes, this is wrong:

```
$imageNode = $imageNode->appendChild($cdata);
```

You should really check the manual again for all functions you make use of. Just to ensure you *know* what those functions return.